# Trying to visualize activations in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I created a simple cnn to detect custom digits and I am trying to visualize the activations of my layers. When I run the following code `layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[:9]]` I get the error `Layer conv2d has no inbound nodes`
When I searched online, it said to define input shape of first layer, but I've already done that and I'm not sure why that is happening. Below is my model.

```
class myModel(Model):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same',
                        input_shape=(image_height, image_width, num_channels))
    self.maxPool1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))
    
    self.conv2 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')
    self.maxPool2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))
    
    self.conv3 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')
    self.maxPool3 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2))
    
    
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    
def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.maxPool1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.maxPool2(x)
    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.maxPool3(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    x = self.d2(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stated goal and what you've posted, I believe the problem here is slightly (and very understandably) misunderstanding the way the TensorFlow APIs work. The model object and its constituent parts only store state for the model, not the evaluation of it, for example the hyperparameters you've set and the parameters the model learns when its fed training data. Even if you worked to fix the problem with what you're trying, the `.output` of the layer objects as part of the model wouldn't return the activations you want to visualize. It instead returns the part of the TensorFlow graph that represents that part of the computation.

For what you want to do, you'll need to manipulate an object that's the result of calling the `.predict` function on the model that you've set up and trained. Or you could drop down to below the Keras abstractions and manipulate the tensors directly.

If I gave this more thought, there's probably a reasonably elegant way to get this by only evaluating your graph (i.e., calling `.predict`) once, but the most obvious naïve way is simply to instantiate several new models (or several subclasses of your model) with each of the layers of interest as the terminal output, which should get you what you want.

For example, you could do something like this for each of the layers whose outputs you're interested in:

```
my_test_image = # get an image
input = Input(shape=(None, 256, 256, 3)) # input size will need to be set according to the relevant model
outputs_of_interest = Model(input, my_model.layers[-2].output)
outputs_of_interest.predict(my_test_image) # <=== this has the output you want
```